# Application running on localhost not able to enable camera microphone when access from mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, camera, webrtc

How can I allow my application to access mobile camera when trying to access http://ip-address:8080 from my mobile phone.
Side note: It works fine when I run it on my computer where application is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run it on server. Because your browser can block some operations on localhost to make your privacy better.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed this on heroku server and it responded properly

Answer (score 0):

The `getUserMedia()` is only allow on secure (https) connections or localhost.
This is why it does work on your pc in localhost.

If you want to access your application by the ip on your phone you must enable https on your application to use your camera/microphone.